# Does easyJet allow a "personal item"?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, easyjet

Standard hand luggage policy for most airlines allows a "single" carry-on bag of (roughly) 50 x 40 x 20cm, "plus a personal item".  The [baggage allowance for easyJet](http://www.easyjet.com/en/planning/baggage) however makes no mention of a 'personal item.'  Should this be interpreted to mean that a second, smaller bag is prohibited (or not free)?  Or is it an oversight?

I'm hoping for the experience of someone who has actually flown with easyJet with "one bag + one personal item".

Comment: Now only 1 item is allowed unless you pay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is [no](http://support.easyjet.com/case-6017).

> Your one ‘cabin bag’ covers a bag, laptop case, brief case, handbag,
>   bumbag, rucksack, carrier bag or wedding dress carrier. Motorcycle
>   helmets are also allowed as/within cabin baggage (providing they
>   follow the relevant size dimensions).
>
> Please note that all these items will be classed as your one cabin
>   bag.

Comment: That was my suspicion. Thanks. I guess I'll be getting up at 5am to fly with Ryan Air instead of easyJet at noon :)

Comment: So, did this change in 2015?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is *yes*. Per the easyJet [baggage page](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage):

> easyJet Plus, FLEXI fare, Upfront and Extra Legroom customers:
>
> One cabin bag as above
> Plus ONE additional small under seat bag (For example a handbag or laptop)
> Maximum size of 45 x 36 x 20cm which will need to be placed under the seat in front.

45x36x20 is one of the largest personal items allowed in the industry.

This change was introduced in [2015](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/easyjet-baggage-allowance-rules-changed-so-only-premium-passengers-get-to-keep-their-bags-10449810.html).

Comment: Please note that this policy appears to be for people who are paying extra to begin with, so if you're a bog-standard economy customer, 1 bag is probably still the limit.

Answer (score 4):

@mkennedy already quoted easyjet's policy but I can add a bit of personal experience. I fly regularly with them and I have often seen other passengers being asked to fit a laptop bag or a handbag in their carry-on, lest they have to check it in. Sometimes people get away with a small purse or a plastic bag but they really mean one bag in total and seem to be quite strict about it.