# Which airlines do not allow a personal item in addition to a carry-on?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage

From experience, most airlines allow passengers to bring a personal item on-board in addition to a carry-on item. I nearly always travel with both but once while flying Amazonas in Bolivia, it was not the case and I had to scramble stuffing things from my carry-on into my personal item and the rest into a piece of checked-luggage. Luckily I had spare space but this is rarely the case.

For information on what is a personal item we already have [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/additional-cabin-handbag-on-flights). We already have plenty of separate questions about specific airlines allowing personal items or not: [Spirit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81171/personal-item-on-spirit-airlines), [EasyJet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37158/does-easyjet-allow-a-personal-item) and [Hop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78934/does-hop-airlines-allow-for-a-personal-item) for instance. Plus, I recently had to ask the same of [Gol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84070/does-gol-airlines-allow-a-personal-item-in-addition-to-a-carry-on) since it's another carrier which I have not flown with before.

**Which airlines do not allow a personal item in addition to a carry-on??**

Could we have a list for all such airlines, since they appear to be the exception rather than the norm, in order to know which airlines to avoid when needing to carry a personal item as well as a carry-on?

Comment: Good question! I actually thought Ryanair did that too, but your question made me look it up and no, they also accept personal items.

Comment: To those who put the question on hold, what is wrong with having a list? There are several already on different topics. Otherwise we end up with one question per airline which is a pain to sift though and even that, someone downvoted the question for GOL, not sure why it's different than Spirit or Easyjet since the airline site is not clear about the topic.

Comment: I agree, a list would be great. Perhaps not always complete, but we have more answers that aren't complete. At least you'd have verification if the airline you take is on the list.

Comment: I think it's too broad as a global question. Maybe if you phrased it as "what airlines in Brasil" it would be more compact and maintainable.

Comment: Given this is the exception rather than the norm, I think the answer would be quite short. Actually, we only found 4 so far. Narrowed to a single country would be of little use, since there are usually not many domestic airlines even for one of the largest countries in the world such as Brazil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following airlines are known to not allow for a personal item in addition to a carry-on:

- [Easyjet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37158/32134), except [some cases](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/84110/36405)
- Amazonas (Source: Experience flying with them)
- Emirates, unless flying business class
- Virgin Atlantic

Comment: Posting this as a community wiki with the obvious example I know of and hoping that others jump in to fill the list.

Comment: Wrong and I answered this elsewhere: purchasing a better seat gives you personal item on easyJet and one of the largest, or possibly the largest personal item, even.

Comment: @chx was assuming the regular fares but you are right nonetheless, thanks for correcting and +1 to your linked answer.